# Dynamically added Image View disappears onPause() or when rotating device

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-orientation

I seem to be going bald trying to fix what probably is a very simple problem.

I have an activity in which users can click a button and an `ImageView` is dynamically added to the screen. This `ImageView` is also stored in an `ArrayList`. When the user pauses the activity or the device is rotated all the images added to the layout disappears. They are still stored in the `ArrayList` however. I attempted to loop through the `ArrayList` to add the images to the layout again, however then I get an error thrown - the specified child already has a parent.

Below is my code for adding images to the layout and the ArrayList

```
public void AddImage() {

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.top);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    iv = new ImageView(this);
    id++;
    iv.setId(id);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.foo);

    iv.setLayoutParams(params);
    rl.addView(iv);
    arrayList.add(iv);
}
```

Comment: Use saveInstaceState for Saving your arrayList refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15362869/1935890

Comment: I think application lifecycle is a good place to start. If I remember right, but its some time ago. rotation triggers it.

Comment: @DixitPatel The ArrayList is stored in saveInstanceState. The list itself is saved and loaded perfectly fine. It's just the actual images that doesn't appear again

Comment: @Linn do u find the solution??

Comment: @AvadhaniY Unfortunately nothing substantial. I'm doing a workaround now where I completely kill the activity and save the ArrayList in Shared Preferences. On start I retrieve Shared Preferences, loop through the ArrayList and dynamically add the ImageViews again. It works, but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Map instead of List and then do something like :

```
map.put(imageViewId,R.drawable.imageViewResource);
```

Then after pause just do :

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.top);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rl.findViewById(imageViewId);

Integer imageViewResource = map.get(imageViewId);
imageView.setImageResource(imageViewResource);
```

If this will not update your image try to :

```
        imageView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
             imageView.setImageResource(imageViewResource);
        }
    });
```

If your map is empty after rotation and you haven't time to play with save/restore instance state, just make map static.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your imageview variable within the scope of the method:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
```

You cannot reuse the variable once it is added.

Answer (score 0):

Add configChanges for that activity in manifest

```
    <activity name="Your ClassName with Package" android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

and call your method `AddImage()` in `OnCongigurationChanged` as below:

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    int ot = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    switch (ot) {
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        AddImage();
        break;
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
        AddImage();
        break;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return super.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add configChanges for that activity in manifest

```
    <activity
    ....
    android:configChanges="orientation" 
    .... >
```