# onRestoreInstance not getting called while switching between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I m trying to switch between two activities . 
In activity 1, i have Button named **GoToSecond** to goto second activity.
In the same way,in activity 2, have Button named **GoToFirst** to goto first activity.

**I have used log messages in first activity .**

Order I m getting when GoToSecond button is clicked  is 
onCreate

onStart

onResume

**onSaveInstance**

onStop

and it switches to second activity .
Now in second activity when i click button GoToFirst , first activity opens and 
log order in first activity is

onCreate

onStart

onResume ..

why **onRestoreInstance** is not getting called after onStart?
even if instance is stored??

Can anyne help me?

Here is the code of first activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText hello;
Button b1;
public static String TAG="Prajwal";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    hello=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    Log.d(TAG,"OnCreate counter 1");
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
});
```

I havent added log messages in code .

And second activity code is

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
              startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG,"Oncreate 2");

}
```

For example 
If i hv an EditText in first activity , and if i hav some text in it , I m losing that text while switching between 2nd activity to 1st activity . bcoz onCreate is called in first activity.
But when i switch to landscape mode onRestoreInstance is called and i m not losing any text .

Comment: Post the code of your first `Activity` please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, onRestoreInstance will get called only if your activity will be destroyed and created again. So in this case your will **restore** previous state of destroyed activity.

But in your case activity isn't destroyed, it just stopped by the system, so it is not loose its state, so no need to restore it.

Please see these links for more details: [FIRST](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState), [SECOND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362525/when-is-onrestoreinstancestate-called)

**Edited**

Since you provided code of your Activities, as I see, you open from second activity not first activity, but third activity with type of first Activity.
So your stacktrace after pressing on button in second Activity would be:

MainActivity -> Main2Activity -> MainActivity.

So you have two simple solutions:
1) Instead of

```
Intent i=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Just write `finish();`

2) Add flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to intent from Main2Activity to MainActivity

Comment: oh. But when If i hv an EditText in first activity , and if i hav some text in it , I m losing that text while switching between 2nd activity to 1st activity . bcoz onCreate is called

Comment: @Prajwal could you please provide code of your activity?

Comment: sure now i hv added

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my answer. In short you not returning to first activity you create ThirdActivity

Comment: Thanks I got the solution  :)  I didnt know that it will be considered as 3rd activity